# AS in multiple Select

Tags: mysql, select

Is it possible to use AS within multiple selects?
something like:

```
SELECT O.order_id, Sum(Order_Tot) FROM
(SELECT P.price * O.qty as Order_Tot FROM crOrdersToProducts O
JOIN tblProducts P ON O.style_id = P.id)
GROUP BY O.order_id
```

Trying to use one query to display order totals by order id.

Answer (score 0):

```
//try this query

SELECT OT.order_id, Sum(OT.Order_Tot) FROM
(SELECT O.order_id,P.price * O.qty as Order_Tot FROM crOrdersToProducts O
JOIN tblProducts P ON O.style_id = P.id) as OT
GROUP BY OT.order_id
```

Comment: Sweet! Fixed the error : #1248 - Every derived table must have its own alias. Thanks